# Realme C15 stuck on bootloop

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, realme

I know this is stupid, but I was trying to install LineageOS to my device using TWRP, while following a tutorial. The os successfully installed, yet my phone boots to TWRP repeatedly. Because I was so desperate, I accidentally flashed the os to the recovery. As a result, the phone infinitely restarts on its own. I can't execute adb/fastboot commands on the device anymore. I felt very sorry for myself. Is there any workaround to this?
My phone model is Realme C15 RMX2180

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to boot into fastboot mode by holding the volume up and power keys (as is for Realme C20) or some other key combination different from the one for recovery. Then you have to flash a recovery image (TWRP or the stock one) using fastboot, and I guess you know what to do from there